# How to convert integer to date Postgres dblink

Tags: php, date, casting, int, dblink

I have a `int` variable containing value eg. `31012015` but I tried to cast to date format `eg` to `dd-mm-yyyy`. Part of my query is:

```
select * from dblink(
  'dbname=dbexample port=5432 host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres password=root', 
  'select * from tableexample where fconclusion between 2014-01-02 and 2014-12-31')
as k(
  id_principal integer, 
  nestrategia smallint, 
  ctitulo character varying(300), 
  factivacion date, 
  nestado smallint,
  fcreacion timestamp without time zone, 
  id_usuario integer, 
  nstatus smallint, 
  nmunicipio smallint, 
  nactividad smallint,
  fconclusion date, 
  id_personal integer, 
  nactivo smallint, 
  fmodificacion date, 
  nconclusion smallint
)
```

`PgAdmin` show the next error:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: date> = integer
>   HINT: No operator matches the name and type of arguments. You may need to add explicit type conversions.
>   CONTEXT: Error Occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute query.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```php
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $int);
echo $dt->format('d-m-Y');
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/308925)**</kbd>